# How can I parse multiple date columns in Pandas?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a field/column in a .csv file that I am loading into Pandas that will not parse as a datetime data type in Pandas. I don't really understand why. I want both FirstTime and SecondTime to parse as datetime64 in Pandas DataFrame.

```
# Assigning a header for our data
header = ['FirstTime', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'SecondTime', 'Col4',
          'Col5', 'Col6', 'Col7', 'Col8']

# Loading our data into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('MyData.csv', names=header, parse_dates=['FirstTime', 'SecondTime'])
```

The code above will only parse SecondTime as datetime64[ns]. FirstTime is left as a Object data type. If I do the following code instead:

```
# Assigning a header for our data
header = ['FirstTime', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'SecondTime', 'Col4',
          'Col5', 'Col6', 'Col7', 'Col8']

# Loading our data into a dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('MyData.csv', names=header, parse_dates=['FirstTime'])
```

It still will not parse FirstTime as a datetime64[ns].

The format for both columns is the same:

```
# Example FirstTime 
# (%f is always .000)
2015-11-05 16:52:37.000

# Example SecondTime
# (%f is always .000)
2015-11-04 15:33:15.000
```

What am I missing here? Is the first column not able to be datetime by default or something in Pandas?

Comment: Could you post a few rows of data with columns through `Col4`?

Comment: You can try `df.FirstTime = to_datetime(df.FirstTime)` to check if there are any issues with the content that prevent conversion independent of the `read_csv` parameter settings.

Comment: Fastidious - I cannot replicate your problem.  Executing your code with pandas 0.16.2 yielded the two columns with dtype datetime64[ns].  Please post your a sample of your data lines and your version of pandas.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't want to share a full sample to protect my own data, but the first column is exactly as it's shown in the above. I have 10 fields of data with comma delimiters. First is Datetime as shown, second is a encrypted ID (20 characters long), Next 3 are Text fields, Then the SecondTime as shown above, then the rest are numeric values. Nothing in any of these fields needs escaping or anything.

Comment: I even tried copying the entire field with date_parse={NewDate: 'FirstTime'} etc. It copied the entire field to a new field called NewDate with no DateTime data type.

Comment: Try reading a file containing this line:  "2015-11-05 16:52:37.000,A,B,C,2015-11-04 15:33:15.000,4,5,6,7,8".  If you can read the dates successfully with your code, then it may be the formatting of your original file.

Comment: Made a new csv, added the row of data, loaded it into a dataframe with parse_dates ignored. No datetime set. Did the same test again, specified both columns in parse_dates and the result was two datetime's. So, I guess it's my formatting. I wonder if there is a footer at the end of the file that is not a datetime... It's about 100MB file, so it's not easy to open hrrm.

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
df = pd.read_csv('MyData.csv', names=header, parse_dates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out in one of my date variables there is an integer cell. So, python recognize it as "object" and the other one is recognized as "int64". You need to make sure both variables are integer.
You can use df.dtypes to see the format of your vaiables.